# How to override a parent resource dictionary property in a MAUI application?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui

I have created a class library which defines some Styles and Colors in ResourceDictionary objects. These are referenced in several MAUI apps, in each of their App.xaml file, like so:

```
<myParentLibrary:ControlStyles/>
<myParentLibrary:Colors/>
```

Now each of my apps obviously have their own Color schemes and styles so they also incluse them like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
```

It is important to note that the names of the Color values defined in the parent class library and the apps are the same because I want the class library to provide a base color but ultimately use the value defined by the app.

To illustrate that consider the following scenario:

(from class library)

```
<Style x:Key="ExampleStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
</Style>

<Color x:Key="Primary">Red</Color>
```

(from App)

```
<Color x:Key="Primary">Blue</Color> <!-- This is from the Colors.xaml file of app -->
<Label Style="{StaticResource ExampleStyle}"/> <!-- This is from a Page in the app -->
```

**-> How do I have the color of the label set as Red, and not Blue ? Is that possible in a scenario similar to what I describe here ?**

Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official document about [Merge resource dictionaries from other assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-8.0#merge-resource-dictionaries-from-other-assemblies):

> When merged ResourceDictionary resources share identical x:Key
> attribute values, .NET MAUI uses the following resource precedence:
>
> 1. The resources local to the resource dictionary.
> 2. The resources
>    contained in the resource dictionaries that were merged via the
>    MergedDictionaries collection, in the reverse order they are listed in
>    the MergedDictionaries property.

And then I created a sample to test:

Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

And the code in the App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:MyClassLibraty.Resources;assembly=MyClassLibraty"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp7"
             x:Class="MauiApp7.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <lib:MyColor/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I declared `<Color x:Key="Primary">#13F444</Color>` in the `MyColor` of the class library and then use it in the page:

```
<Label
     Text="Hello, World!"
     TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
     Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
     SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />
```

Finally, the label used the `Primary` key in MyColor.xaml of the class library instead of the default `Primary` key in Colors.xaml:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to globally reference resources in the class library itself? So a XAML in class library can use those resources?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Just add the dictionary as the ContentPage's resource. @HamidZ